# SQL query or stored procedure: the data in one column is transposed and sorted by descend based on other columns

Tags: sql, database

If Order no. is same, data on column FBH is required to transposed from column to row, and the sequence is sorted by "largest to smallest" order.

Old table:

```
Order no.   Column 1    Column 2    FBH
18046352-3  A       0.40
18046352-3  A       0.41
18046352-3  A       0.45
18046352-3      B   0.43
18046352-3      B   0.42
18046352-3      B   0.43
18066235-4  C   D   0.27
12345678-1  E   F   0.71
```

New Table

```
Order no.   Column 1    Column 2    FBH-1   FBH-2   FBH-3   FBH-4   FBH-5   FBH-6
18046352-3  A   B   0.45    0.44    0.43    0.42    0.41    0.40
18066235-4  C   D   0.27                    
12345678-1  E   F   0.71
```

Thank you so much,
Frank

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, please show both sample input and expected result as tables with text here in your question, don't assume people will risk to land on external, unkown pages and then even write all texts again because it's not possible to copy it from a screenshot when they want to try out a possible solution. Furthermore, keep in mind SO is no code writing service, but should assist on a specific issue. So please show  your attempt(s) and explain clearly what didn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I do my best to update my question, but it isn't perfect because SO doesn't provide a function to draw table. If you know something for describing question better, feel free to let me know. Anything will be welcomed.

Comment: SO does provide the option to create tables, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post You still didn't show what you tried and what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly it should be what you looking for:

```
WITH
    FUNCTION get_max_n(p_order_no VARCHAR2, p_column_1 CHAR, p_column_2 CHAR, p_n NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
        l_n_top NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT fbh INTO l_n_top FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                order_no
                , MAX(column_1) OVER (PARTITION BY order_no) column_1
                , MAX(column_2) OVER (PARTITION BY order_no) column_2
                , FBH
                , DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY order_no ORDER BY FBH DESC ) AS row_rank
            FROM 
                SC_TST_PIVOT_TMP
        )
        WHERE
            order_no = p_order_no
            AND column_1 = p_column_1
            AND column_2 = p_column_2
            AND row_rank = p_n;
        
        RETURN l_n_top;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RETURN NULL;
    END;
    
SELECT 
    order_no, column_1, column_2
    , get_max_n(order_no, column_1, column_2, 1) "FBH-1"
    , get_max_n(order_no, column_1, column_2, 2) "FBH-2"
    , get_max_n(order_no, column_1, column_2, 3) "FBH-3"
    , get_max_n(order_no, column_1, column_2, 4) "FBH-4"
    , get_max_n(order_no, column_1, column_2, 5) "FBH-5"
    , get_max_n(order_no, column_1, column_2, 6) "FBH-6"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        order_no
        , MAX(column_1) OVER (PARTITION BY order_no) column_1
        , MAX(column_2) OVER (PARTITION BY order_no) column_2
        , FBH row_rank
    FROM 
        SC_TST_PIVOT_TMP
) GROUP BY order_no, column_1, column_2
```

Let me know and have a good day, Seb ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @Seb. I'm not a DB developer, could you do me a favor? How do I use your SQL script? May I just copy your query script directly to SSMS, and execute it? Or do I need to add other code to convert the table to what I need? Like this,

SELECT TOP (1000) [order_no]
      ,[Column_1]
      ,[Column_2]
      ,[FBH]
  FROM [DB name].[dbo].[Table name]

Comment: Hey, this solution is created in Oracle SQL Developer so I don't know how it will exactly works in SSMS but it should be very similar.

Just replace SC_TST_PIVOT_TMP to your source table and when MSSQL would have trouble with WITH function (get_max_n) just create it separately and then run lower part of query